# How do I logged XML body in nestjs-soap

Tags: xml, soap, nestjs

The API I'm trying to send request is http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx
I'm import this in my Module

```js
imports: [
     SoapModule.forRoot({
      clientName: process.env.APP_NAME,
      uri: process.env.URL,
      clientOptions: {},
    }),
]
```

then I just called it in my service

```js
constructor(
@Inject(process.env.APP_NAME)
private readonly soapClient: Client,
){}

return await this.soapClient.AddAsync({
      intA: 1,
      intB: 2,
});
```

Then this code is work fine. but I want to see XML body that send to that website. anyway or log it?

Comment: It is the body of the request.  Try this.soapClient.Body  It may be a stream so you may need to read the stream.

Comment: found it. It's this.soapClient.lastRequest this will get XML of last request

Answer (score 0):

Found that I can use `this.soapClient.lastRequest` after call `this.soapClient.Function`. This will get XML that send with `this.soapClient.lastRequest`

final code is like

```js
constructor(
@Inject(process.env.APP_NAME)
private readonly soapClient: Client,
){}

async myServiceFunction() {
    const result = await this.soapClient.AddAsync({
      intA: 1,
      intB: 2,
    });

    return this.soapClient.lastRequest;
  }
```

the respond in postman look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/"
    xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/">
    <soap:Body>
        <Add xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <intA>1</intA>
            <intB>2</intB>
        </Add>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

now this is the way I found. any way better like create body before running `await this.soapService.SoapFunction({body})` feel free to share. This is my first time working with SOAP